# Outlook keeps asking for login credentials during setup

Tags: contacts, outlook

I'm trying to switch from a windows mobile to android. My main problem is moving contacts which are saved on windows mobile in an outlook account.

Therefore i tried to download and configure outlook on Android, but have no luck on entering the user credentials.

The following happens:

1. I enter the email (which does NOT end in '@outlook.com', i used a normal mail address to sign in at outlook which works with outlook on windows 10, windows mobile and web).
2. I enter the password.
3. After entering the password the outlook app authenticates on android and gives a message, that the server configuration is updated, and i need to re-enter password.
4. I reenter the password.
5. I'm asked if the application is allowed to access outlook and answer yes.
6. Password question step 2 appears. From this moment step 2-5 are endless loops.

What i've tried so far:

- Delete the app cache
- Delete the app, reinstall it from play store

Both did not work, same behaviour as before occurred.

I have tried to enter another outlook account ending with outlook.com - only one time password was needed and everything works - but as this is not the account with contacts it is not so useful.

So how can i enter my main outlook address to outlook? Or is there another way to get windows phone contacts to android?

Comment: See [answers here](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Windows+contacts+to+android) for windows to Android contacts​ transfer

Comment: @beeshyams thanks found a workaround. Add a second outlook.com-alias online to the existing account and log in with this alias. then you can easily send the contacts from outlook to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

there seems to be a bug if you use outlook accounts which are not ending on outlook.com.

If you go to https:\login.live.com you can login with other credentials.
There is a menü "Your Informations" where you can edit the email or telefon alias.
In this menü you can create an outlook.com alias.

With this outlook.com alias login from Outlook on outlook mobile to Outlook.com works and contacts can be retrieved.